# Can't print the proper values of Python dictionary in HTML

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I'm trying to parse a Python dictionary into HTML and display it as a table.
I have an SQL database that I draw data from using Python, then parse it into my page like so:

```
tusername = query_db("SELECT t_username FROM teacher")    
return render_template('teachers.html.',username=tusername)
```

I found this piece of code here, which prints the data:

```
<table>
    {% for t in table %}
        <tr>
        {% for i in t %}
            <td>{{ i }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This is what it prints:

```
t_username
t_username
t_username
t_username
t_username
```

This is my data:

```
[{'t_username': '1'}, {'t_username': 'admin'}, {'t_username': 'dfsdsfdf'}, {'t_username': 'NewGuy'}, {'t_username': 'test'}]
```

I want it to print the proper names rather than `"t_username"`. I've not been able to find a solution and I've only just begun working with Python, so I'm not very familiar with it. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `t` is a dictionary, `{% for i in t %}` iterates over it's keys (i.e. a single `t_username` key). Instead just output the value by the key:

```
{% for t in table %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ t.t_username }}</td>    
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```